# Convert two lists to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, t-test

I conducted t test on two data frames and stored results in two separate variables. They turned out to be lists. Now, I want to make a dataframe of t scores and p-values but I am not sure how to do that. I guess the lists are s3 class. The code.

```
AML_ttest <- apply(aml_df,1,t.test)
nrml_ttest <- apply(nrml_df,1,t.test)
```

Running `AML_ttest[[9]]` gives the following result.

```
One Sample t-test

data:  newX[, i]
t = 25.994, df = 25, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 6.612063 7.749997
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  7.18103
```

How I can get the t and p-value from each list element? And make a new dataframe?

Thanks.

#### ---UPDATE---

I tried the following code.

```
# AML
AML_ttest <- apply(aml_df,1,t.test)
AML_ttest = do.call(rbind,AML_ttest)
res_AML_ttest <- AML_ttest[,c("statistic","p.value")]

# Normal
nrml_ttest <- apply(nrml_df,1,t.test)
nrml_ttest = do.call(rbind,nrml_ttest)
res_nrml_ttest <- nrml_ttest[,c("statistic","p.value")]

# Make df
df_ttest <- data.frame(res_AML_ttest, res_nrml_ttest)
df_ttest

# Output
     statistic   p.value    statistic.1 p.value.1
1    56.71269 6.171562e-28    144.5161 1.569932e-52
2    75.79649 4.559861e-31    74.87025 5.317292e-42
3    17.68306 1.207297e-15    15.15478 1.891711e-17
4    108.4904 5.984139e-35    168.8557 4.993433e-55
5    152.8165 1.156183e-38    192.4672 3.959361e-57
6    63.21714 4.163004e-29    90.42468 5.112986e-45
```

Is this approach good? AM I good to go?

Comment: That apparently works, so yes, you're good to go. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll test with this sample data:

```r
TT1 <- apply(mtcars[1:3], 2, t.test)
```

We can peek at the `str`ucture of one of them to see what names to look for.

```r
str(TT1[[1]])
# List of 10
#  $ statistic  : Named num 18.9
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
#  $ parameter  : Named num 31
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
#  $ p.value    : num 1.53e-18
#  $ conf.int   : num [1:2] 17.9 22.3
#   ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
#  $ estimate   : Named num 20.1
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of x"
#  $ null.value : Named num 0
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean"
#  $ stderr     : num 1.07
#  $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#  $ method     : chr "One Sample t-test"
#  $ data.name  : chr "newX[, i]"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

This suggests we can use `"statistic"` and `"p.value"` for that. A direct approach:

```r
TT1[[1]][ c("statistic", "p.value") ]
# $statistic
#        t 
# 18.85693 
# $p.value
# [1] 1.526151e-18
```

We can gather them together with something like:

```r
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(TT1, `[`, c("statistic", "p.value")))
out
#      statistic      p.value
# mpg   18.85693 1.526151e-18
# cyl   19.59872 5.048147e-19
# disp  10.53069 9.189065e-12
```

where `mpg` and such are row-names. They can be brought in to the frame itself if needed,

```r
out$name <- rownames(out)
rownames(out) <- NULL # aesthetics only, not required
out
#   statistic      p.value name
# 1  18.85693 1.526151e-18  mpg
# 2  19.59872 5.048147e-19  cyl
# 3  10.53069 9.189065e-12 disp
```

(Since you made your list of t-tests with `apply(MARGIN=1)`, though, it may not be named meaningfully if the original data did not have good row names.)

Answer (score 0):

Having a little more data in your example generally helps, but we can get p values and so forth without that in this case. Try `AML_ttest[[9]]$p.value`. To see all the options, try `str(AML_ttest[[9]])` or `str(summary(AML_ttest[[9]]))`.

The package `broom` is really nice for this. Try `broom::t.test(MyData)`. If you've grouped your data by some variable using tidyverse syntax, you could do, e.g., `MyData %>% group_by(ColumnA) %>% do(tidy(t.test(.$ColumnB, .$ColumnC, paired = TRUE)))`. (Pay attention to the ".")

Comment: Updated my question with adding code, please have a look at it